# Create Credit note, PayPal do not refund

Tags: magento, paypal

I created credit note  for a order (the paid and invoiced). The credit note is saved. It also should the refund the money in PayPal. But it doesn't. What can go wrong?

Edit1:
Which function is called when refund is called?

Answer (score 0):

Did you capture your payment? What is the invoice status? 
It should be ‘Paid’. If it’s paid and captured within paypal you should be able to refund online. It should have a transaction ID with it, then make sure you click refund and not refund offline

Comment: Yes, I have invoice marked as paid, it also payment also have transaction id. I wonder which function get called internally (in Magento module) when we do refund

Answer (score 0):

In the model of your payment module, there must be a file named `PaymentMethod.php` having a function `refund(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)` which is responsible for this.